# nothing to do! sdk tools directory is missing ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools, ubuntu-18.04

i'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1
and i installed the android-sdk by using this code in terminal :
sudo apt-get install android-sdk 
and it worked but when i'm trying to path the sdk folder i installed, find no directory in /home/$user/... that sdk exist!
anybody knows where it's installed?

Comment: Android Studio already incorporates the Android SDK, you don't need to install it separately.

Comment: I found the problem.
it's because of my IP address, I'm from Iran and that's why android studio do not download the SDK tools and other components...(Iran is under the USA sanctions)

Answer (score -1):

If you are behind a proxy, do **NOT** configure the **Automatic proxy configuration URL** (URL to .pac file), because this didn't worked for me.

Configure the proxy **manually**, this fixed it for me.